# window.opener is null in 'Office 2013 mail app' in 'Outlook 2016 for mac'

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365-apps, office-app, outlook-2016

I have created a mail app using Office 2013 and visual studio. It points to our webpage which has few hyperlinks. We open new windows on clicking these hyperlinks. The app works fine in outlook for desktop with my Office 365 account. However, issue arises when I add my Office 365 account in Outlook 2016 for mac and try to access my app from there. The windows open but do not honour any specifications that we provide e.g. height, width, etc. Also, window.opener is always null so we cannot return any data to the original window. Any idea?

`window.open(url, title, "height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",location=0,directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=1")`